# Can one show corbordism invariance of the Crane-Yetter state-sum using simplicial methods / are there 'Pachner-like' moves for cobordisms?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, simplicial-stuff, cobordism, topological-quantum-field-theory, braided-tensor-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote some Unitary Braided Modular Fusion Category. It is well known that the Crane-Yetter state-sum, $Z_{CY}(\bullet|\mathcal{C})$ is an oriented-cobordism invariant. In other words, let $N^5$ be a 5-manifold with $\partial N^5=M_1^4 \sqcup \bar{M}_2^4$, which is a cobordism between 4-manifolds $M_1,M_2$. Then $Z_{CY}(M_1|\mathcal{C}) = Z_{CY}(M_2|\mathcal{C})$.

Using the fact that the oriented cobordism group $\Omega_4^{SO}=\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $CP^2$ and the bordism invariant of $M$ is the signature $\sigma(M)$, we can express $Z_{CY}(M)$ in terms of the signature of $M$ and the value of $Z_{CY}(CP^2|\mathcal{C})$, in particular as $Z_{CY}(CP^2|\mathcal{C})^{\sigma(M)}$. There are well-known expressions for $Z_{CY}(CP^2|\mathcal{C})$ in terms of the Braided Fusion Category data.

Is there a proof of the cobordism invariance using combinatorial/triangulation-based methods? The proofs I've seen all use fairly abstract skein theory arguments - it'd be illuminating if there were a more hands-on approach.

It would also be nice if there were versions of the Pachner move theorem for cobordisms. In particular, are there a set of additional moves to the Pachner moves that can generate cobordisms, as opposed to just PL homeomorphism? Even comments about some generating set of 4-manifold cobordisms (e.g. via connected sums with some set of manifolds) would be helpful, even if they're not explicity translated into the language of triangulations. Recall that the PL-invariance of $Z_{CY}(\bullet|\mathcal{C})$ can be proved via Pachner moves.

Comment: > It would also be nice if there were versions of the Pachner move theorem for cobordisms.

I'm a bit surprised by this. The Pachner theorem comes from looking at specific triangulations of cylinders, so _restricting_ bordisms to those that induce PL homeomorphisms on the boundaries. If you want to remove that restriction, you don't really have Pachner's theory anymore, but simply triangulated bordisms. I don't know what else you'd expect there.

Answer (score 2):

I know very little about this topic, but I think this may be answered in this paper that studies a cubical analogue of Pachner moves:

Karim Adiprasito and Gaku Liu, [Normal crossing immersions, cobordisms and flips](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01108).

> Abstract: We study various analogues of theorems from PL topology for cubical
> complexes. In particular, we characterize when two PL homeomorphic
> cubulations are equivalent by Pachner moves by showing the question to
> be equivalent to the existence of cobordisms between generic
> immersions of hypersurfaces. This solves a question and conjecture of
> Habegger, Funar and Thurston.

Instead of working with manifolds broken up into $n$-simplices (triangulations), this result concerns manifolds which are broken up into $n$-cubes (a "cubulation") and defines combinatorial rules for going from one cubulation to another via making local changes (Definition 2.1).

Comment: This is interesting, but seems like a special case and doesn't directly answer my question. In particular they only talk about PL homeorphisms of manifolds and cobordisms of some special objects.